# InList constraints values from Config.groovy property

Tags: grails

I defined a simple class with a field that has a inList constraints, I want to load constraints list from a property defined in Config.groovy file

This is the class

```
class User {
  String email
  String department

  static constraints = {
    email unique:true
    department inList:["ABC", "DEF", "EGF", "ETC"]
  }
}
```

and config property

```
app.departments = ["ABC", "DEF", "EGF", "ETC"]
```

i would like to load my inList constraints values from config.groovy property is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holders can be used in this case.

```
import grails.util.Holders

class User {
  String email
  String department

  static constraints = {
    email unique:true
    department inList: Holders.config.app.departments
  }
}

//config
app.departments = ["ABC", "DEF", "EGF", "ETC"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Holders

```
department inList: Holders.config.app.departments
```