# Internationalization in inList

Tags: grails, internationalization

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789389/inlist-constraints-values-from-config-groovy-property) and it was very useful to what i want to do, but is there is way to make what in the **inList** follow the **Grails Internationalization**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found [workaround](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/grails-scaffolding-enums-and-i18n/) , i think it may help ..

> ## 1. toString()
>
> As you know, the scaffolded screens just output values in selects and dropdowns through the toString() method of the shown object. We can construct each enum with a hardcoded translation and have toString() return that value.

```
 class Product {

enum Status {

    AVAILABLE("Beschikbaar"), SOLD_OUT("Uitverkocht")

    final String value
    Status(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    String toString() {
        value
    }
}

String name
Status status

static constraints = { name blank: false, unique: true }
}
```

> The actual names of the enum now only appear in the generated HTML:

```
 <select name="status" required="" id="status" >
 <option value="AVAILABLE" >Beschikbaar</option>
  <option value="SOLD_OUT" >Uitverkocht</option>
  </select>
```

> ## 2. MessageSourceResolvable
>
> By now you’ll probably understand above hardcoded solution works for just one language, one hardcoded in the enum itself – which will cause problems when in a month from now your application actually needs to support a 2nd language :-) So how do we leverage the fact that we have already have message_XX.properties where we’ve put our other message keys?
>   Use the underlying Spring framework. Have our enum implement org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable e.g. like this:

```
enum Status implements org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable {

AVAILABLE, SOLD_OUT

public Object[] getArguments() { [] as Object[] }

public String[] getCodes() { [ name() ] }

public String getDefaultMessage() { "?-" + name() }
}
```

> Now we can provide a value in our messages_nl.properties for each enum we have:

```
product.label=Product
product.name.label=Naam
product.status.label=Status
AVAILABLE=Beschikbaar
SOLD_OUT=Uitverkocht
```